# Ionic App -IOS local time issue -but working fine in android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I’ve an issue on my ionic app. My app is a barcode scanning system which ends up in sign in and signs out. After sign in it shows sign in time which is showing the correct local time in Android but showing wrong time in iOS with a difference of 5 hours. I tried UTC time conversion as well as date formatting, but still failing.

```
 private _formatedLocalTime(date: Date) {
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours()  + ":" + date.getMinutes();
  }
```

Comment: can you add snapshot of ionic info

Comment: @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.1

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.11.1
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 10